# Is it possible to not move?

Tags: special-relativity

Whenever we consider velocity, it is always from a frame of reference.

This means that if I am travelling .5c, I'm travelling at a speed between the speed of light and my current frame of references' speed.

Hence, is it theoretically possible for something to "not move"?  I imagine that it would be completely incapable of ever moving, and impossible for anything that is moving to ever get to that state.  Furthermore, I would imagine that this object would be frozen in time as well.

Is it possible for something to not move, and if so, do we know about anything that doesn't?

Comment: Interesting question. Perhaps take a look at absolute zero: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero

Comment: I always view myself as stationary while the world moves around me. However, the world thinks quite oppositely (it stays still whilst I am the mover).

Comment: An "object" with no spatial or temporal extent is called an *event*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This means that if I am travelling .5c, I'm travelling at a speed
>   between the speed of light and my current frame of references' speed.

This isn't correct; you're at rest with respect to yourself.  Uniform motion is relative.  Two objects may have a *relative* speed of 0.5c but, according to *each* object, it is the *other* object that is travelling at 0.5c.

An object that could "not move" would necessarily be at rest in *every* reference frame otherwise it would be moving according to some observers.  This, it seems to me, is impossible.

There is, however, an invariant speed $c$; an object with speed $c$ in one inertial reference frame has speed $c$ in all inertial reference frames.

Comment: Then could you say that there are only two speeds in the universe, the speed of light, and not the speed of light?  Everything else is simply directional?

Comment: No, everything else is *relative*.

Comment: But you can't say which speed is closer to the speed of light.  If I watch a train pass by, it appears to be closer to the speed of light, but I appear to it to be closer.  Hence, it is impossible for one speed to be greater than another, just in a different direction.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, no, one cannot say that and I don't understand why you would think that.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum mechanically even at absolute zero objects have zero point energy. That is, they are "jiggling about". In a way this is a consequence of the uncertainty principle as they can't have both known location and momentum. I *think* this means that even in its own frame of reference no object is every truly "at rest" - so the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, within the framework of special relativity, being stationary is, well, relative. There are, however, alternate formulations of relativity, which are described by Bacry and Levy-LeBlond in "Possible Kinematics" and commented on by Dyson in "Missed Opportunities".

One of these formulations derives from the so-called Carroll Group. It represents a universe in which all objects have zero velocity, while they may have nonzero momentum. As Carroll wrote in "Through the looking-glass, and what Alice found there,"

> "A slow sort of country," said the Queen, "Now, here, you see, it takes
>   all the running you can do, to keep in the same place."

In such a universe, objects are truly stationary in the absolute sense, while still satisfying Galileo's principle of relativity. I should note that that the Carroll Group probably has not been applied to describe measurable physical phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all things in the universe are always in motion.  We stand on an earth that rotates, wobbles, orbits, expands and contracts, all while following a sun which orbits the milky way, waves up and down during this orbit, and does so within a milky way which itself is moving relative to the rest of the universe.

I believe the sun is moving relative to the local interstellar cloud at 26 km/s or such.  I believe the earths total velocity relative to the point we call the CMB, and where we believe the "Big Bang" took place, is about 600+ km per second, (but this number is from memory, and may be incorrect, sorry).

But the bottom line is, all things in the universe are perpetually in motion.  Significantly.

Hope this perspective helps with your ponderings.